# is there a way to check if a string is of this *x.xx.xxxx* format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want a function to check if a string is of format *x.xx.xxxx* in javascript. For example, s.xf.ssfs should return true. And sx.xf.hsdf should return false. Also s.fsd.sfdf should return false.

Comment: My description from what you've written so far would be "exactly one alphabetic character, a dot, exactly two alpha chars, a dot, exactly four alpha chars" — if that's not correct you'll have to describe your conditions better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex:

```js
const regex = new RegExp('[a-z][.][a-z]{2}[.][a-z]{4}');

console.log(regex.test('s.xf.ssfs'));
console.log(regex.test('s.fsd.sfdf'));
```

As an alternative you can also split the string by periods and check the length of each individual item:

```js
function check(s){
  let a = s.split('.');
  return a.length == 3 && a[0].length == 1 && a[1].length == 2 && a[2].length == 4;
}
console.log(check('s.xf.ssfs'));
console.log(check('sx.xf.hsdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From a brute force approach you could split the string by . into an array and check the length of the array, and each element within the array as follows:

```
let myArray = myString.split(".");   
if(myArray.length !== 3){
   return false 
}      
else if(myArray[0] !== 1 || myArray[1] !== 2 || myArray[3] != 4){
   return false
}          
else{return true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `reducer` version

```js
const isValid = s => s.split('.').reduce((b,a,i) => a.length === [1,2,4][i] ? b+1 : b, 0) === 3
console.log(isValid('s.xf.ssfs'));
console.log(isValid('ds.xf.ssfs'));
console.log(isValid('5.32.9850'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-regex, `for` loop option:

```
const test1 = 's.xf.ssfs';
const test2 = 'sx.xf.hsdf';

function correctFormat(str) {
  if (str.length !== 9) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (str[1] !== '.' || str[4] !== '.') {
    return false;
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (i !== 1 && i !== 4 && str[i] === '.') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(correctFormat(test1));
console.log(correctFormat(test2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are what you are looking for here. Simply define a regex and use the `test()` method to evaluate a string. For example:

```js
const regex = /^[a-z][.][a-z]{2}[.][a-z]{4}$/
console.log(regex.test('s.xf.ssfs'))
console.log(regex.test('sx.xf.hsdf'))
```

If you require to accept letters and numbers you could use this regular expression instead to test against:

```js
const regex = /^.[.].{2}[.].{4}$/
console.log(regex.test('s.5f.s9fs'))
console.log(regex.test('sx.xf.hsdf'))
```